# What do you call the stat breakdown when creating a new character on Ragnarok Online?

Tags: android

I remember when creating a character in RO, there is this hexagonal object where the different points are either str, agi, dex, etc and when you click any of the points the 3d shape in the middle would adjust itself to reflect the values.

I want to know what it is called so I can research properly how to implement it on Android and in a circular border with 5 points. If you have ant libs that can also implement this it would be greatly appreciated!

Attached is a sample image of the stat distribution

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2EEDcqZyzR9MXMTBikgCLWl62fnURjTjFeemrSbuzn_KjkdUMy_1mThurMBN4iiXXJV5RfzscgAS1xe0hQ3-MVY7fbwp9i8oIukJ_pmGaXvGAw=w360-h270-nc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are named **spider web chart** or **radar charts**.
Here's a library: [Github Link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)